# Turning each frame in a 3D animation into a flat grease pencil - possible/viable?

Tags: modeling, animation, grease-pencil

*Full disclaimer: I'm not an animator, my question is based on the perspective of someone on the outside looking in, so I am aware that my question might seem ignorant to hardened veterans of either 3D and/or 2D animation. I mean no disrespect with my question, I just had an idea and I was wondering if that idea is, first of all, possible in Blender to begin with, and second, viable or even practical for someone who actually works in the field. I am aware there are probably lots of issues I'm just not seeing as a non-animator and it may not be as useful as I think it might be.*

I follow the creator of a completely fan-made series based on the Star Fox series, called A Fox in Space (to avoid the wrath of the Nintendo ninjas), and he made the switch from Adobe's line of products to Blender a while ago. It's fascinating to see how he transferred all his knowledge and workflow into Blender and how much better everything looks. It's also easier for him to animate and compose.

Since he's doing a sort of rotoscoped-like art style to mimic the look of old cartoons, I was wondering if there is a way to animate it quicker - not because I'm impatient for the series to finally come out, but because I'm ***really*** lazy and I always try to make things easier for myself or other people.

So my idea is: if he's going for that sort of rotoscoped art style and he's already using Blender, wouldn't it make sense to use actual 3D models as the base? Instead of hand drawing everything from scratch, he could use 3D models to create the base, then touch up on it with the grease pencil tool. The idea is not to completely replace hand drawn animation, but rather to supplement it and make it easier for artists to get all the frames they need.

The way I imagined it to work, *in theory*, would be like this:

- create a model, complete with rigging and everything, but it doesn't need to be a detailed model
- animate said model to the best of your abilities
- turn each frame of the animation into a grease pencil frame, using some kind of process to make sure only the outlines of the different parts of the model (such as faces and clothes) are turned into strokes
- make adjustments to the generated frames to fix any unwanted properties that come from using 3D models

So my question is:

- is something like that even possible in Blender?
- would this even be of use to actual animators? Or would it cause more problems than it's worth?

Comment: Yes, it‘s possible - I would say.

Comment: One of the newest Blender features, Lineart, competes with Freestyle by generating grease pencil curve on meshes instead of drawing pixel on the finished render. So the technology is there. As for viability, very debatable, often 3D is too realistic, often in order to make a good 3D art, you first make a 2D concept art first, so maybe it's not the greatest idea to do the reverse... But it surely would be nice to have an additional workflow and additional possibilities...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I didn't even know that was a thing... then again, I don't know a lot about Blender, otherwise I wouldn't ask these questions. :') Now all I need to figure out is how to flatten the generated Grease Pencil along the camera perspective and figure out how to do that automatically for each frame of animation, EASY. Oh, and also figure out how to rotate each frame to match every other frame in cases where the camera orbits an object for example.