# Flatten points relative to the camera?

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil

Slightly related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230164/turning-each-frame-in-a-3d-animation-into-a-flat-grease-pencil-possible-viable). Taking the default scene as an example, I have the following setup:

[image]

This is the default cube with an empty grease pencil object, which has the line art modifier pointing at the default cube. This is what you get when you apply the line art modifier and remove/hide the default cube:

[image]

The resulting grease pencil points occupy all three axes, which is completely expected given how the line art modifier works, but since I want to edit the result like a regular *flat* grease pencil object, I want to flatten the resulting points along the same rotation as the camera. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit Mode > *Grease Pencil Menu > Clean Up > Reproject Strokes*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/grease_pencil/modes/edit/grease_pencil_menu.html#reproject) will flatten your GP object, with plenty of projection options.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just had to select every point and press 0 to get into the camera view before I select the "View" option. Thanks!