# Keep the shape of a Grease Pencil while moving it closer to the camera

Tags: grease-pencil

Related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230685/flatten-points-relative-to-the-camera). In short, I created a Grease Pencil object using a model as the base by using the Line Art modifier and applying it. I then used "Reproject Strokes - View" to flatten the resulting Grease Pencil object along the camera view.

The point of this is to create a Grease Pencil object from a model, which I can then edit like a regular Grease Pencil object. The original 3d model is simply used as a base.

Works great so far. My problem now though, is that depending on how far away the object is from the center of the scene, the further away the Grease Pencil will be from its original model. See the example below:

[image]

[image]

I want the Grease Pencil to be *on* the model, roughly. In other words, I want to move the Grease Pencil closer to the camera while keeping the shape you see from the camera view. How can I do that?

Comment: Don’t apply the modifier. That’s about it.

Comment: @TheLabCat That's genius! I just wish my "workflow" (if you can call it that) didn't **require** me to apply the modifier in the first place. ;( Thanks for giving me a reason to clarify my question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't answer the specific question posed, it does solve the underlying issue. I had the wrong assumption that "Reproject Strokes - View" always puts the strokes in the center of the scene. This is not true, it puts the strokes in the center of the Grease Pencil object itself. So to solve my issue, all I had to do was move the Grease Pencil object to where the mesh is and **then** reproject the strokes. That way, the strokes would be placed roughly on the model, as I originally wanted.